# Why are some languages not highlighted in an npm project using PrismJS?

Tags: prismjs, spectacle

I'm using [Spectacle](https://formidable.com/open-source/spectacle/) 5 in an npm project, which itself uses Prism as a dependency. The [CodePane](https://formidable.com/open-source/spectacle/docs/tag-api/#codepane) component correctly highlights code for e.g. `python`, but  for e.g. `haskell`, no highlighting is being performed (I verified the same code snippet worked at https://prismjs.com/test.html#language=haskell).

I don't see any errors in the web console to indicate an issue. I wonder if I still need to manually include CSS, or if this is perhaps an issue with Spectacle. Maybe a workaround would be to try to use something like the [prism component loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prismjs-components-loader)? As far as I can tell, npm didn't have components for individual languages, and it seemed to be implied that the default is to load all language components.

Comment: I'll note that Spectacle seems to include haskell in the version of Prism I'm using: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/spectacle/blob/v5.7.0/src/utils/prism-import.js

Comment: I also tried including the css for Haskell+Python from https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-dark&languages=haskell+python in my project, which didn't seem to change anything